# Convert Oracle query into hive

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive, hql

Oracle query:

`select col_name INTO XYZ from table_name where <conditions1 and condition2....>` --- this is getting me the value of the query into variable XYZ, which is not a table but just a flat variable [the oracle query return a single value into XYZ]. This XYZ is then consumed by a other function for comparison eg.  it is used in the query with relational operators like ABC>XYZ (ABC is a variable name).

I could have done this using create table XYZ..as .. clause in hive but then this cant be used with relational operators in hive(ABC>XYZ).

I tried to populate the variable XYZ through shell script like:
hive -e 'select col_name from table_name where ' >a.txt (move the output into a.txt)

temp=cat`a.txt` (now I am able get the value here in temp)

`hive -e 'use database ; set hivevar:XYZ=$temp'`(Now I am trying to set this variable in hive-shell and use it as ${hivevar:XYZ} ) 
here the problem is `temp` is in bash-shell and after running this command it will go to hive-shell and search for `temp` in hive. is there any way such that I can get `temp` in bash set to XYZ=`temp` in hive.

P.S: even tried with hiveconf but same problem as hivevar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific use case, you can run

```
 echo 'use database ; set hivevar:XYZ=$temp' > initFile
 hive -i initFile
```

`hive -i` runs the commands in the initialization file and then opens up hive-shell.